# MongoDB aggregation query to split and convert JSON?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a JSON file with a horrific data structure

```
{ "@timestamp" : "20160226T065604,39Z", 
  "@toplevelentries" : "941", 
  "viewentry" : [ { "@noteid" : "161E", 
        "@position" : "1", 
        "@siblings" : "941", 
        "entrydata" : [
```

and entrydata is a list of 941 entries, each of which look like this

```
        { "@columnnumber" : "0", 
          "@name" : "$Created", 
          "datetime" : { "0" : "20081027T114133,55+01" } 
        }, 
        { "@columnnumber" : "1", 
          "@name" : "WriteLog", 
          "textlist" : { "text" : [ { "0" : "2008.OCT.28 12:54:39 CET # EMI" }, 
                  { "0" : "2008.OCT.28 12:56:13 CET # EMI" },
```

There are many more columns. The structure is always this:

```
{
  "@columnnumber": "17",
  "@name": "PublicDocument",
  "text": {
    "0": "TMI-1-2005.pdf"
  }
}
```

there's a column number which we can throw away, a @name which is the important part, then one of text, datetime or textlist fields where the value is always this weird subdocument with a 0 key and the actual value.

All 941 entries have the same number of these column entries and the column entry is always the same structure. Ie. if `"@columnnumber": "13"` has a `@name: foo` then it'll always be foo and if it has a `datetime` key then it always will have a datetime key, never a text or textlist. This monster was borne out of a SQL or similar database somewhere at the very far end of the pipeline but I have no access to the source beyond this. The goal is to revert the transformation and make it into something a `SELECT` statement would produce (except textlist, although I guess `array_agg` and similar could produce that too).

Is there a way to get 941 separate JSON entries out of MongoDB looking like:

```
{
  $Created: "20081027T114133,55+01",
  WriteLog: ["2008.OCT.28 12:54:39 CET # EMI", "2008.OCT.28 12:56:13 CET # EMI"],
  PublicDocument: "TMI-1-2005.pdf"
}
```

Comment: Not really clear on the structure of the document here. Are you always dealing with `@columnnumber` values of `0` and `1`? Also the aggregation framework ( and rightly so IMHO ) does not transform data points into "keys" in any way. If those are not fixed values in your output ( always just `$Created` and `WriteLog` then mapReduce might be a better option. Still it's not that clear if you are "aggregating" anything, or just looking for a straight transformation of the content. Could be clearer. Also handy to know if array data is fixed to index points always or not.

Comment: Sorry. There are many more columns. Straight transformation, yes. "array data is fixed to index points always or not." I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: BTW. Please don't freak out at the close vote (it's mine right now). It's just the mechanism I use ( as it should be used ) to help prevent non-answers being submitted ( as has been done ) on a question that needs clarification. I always lift the vote if the question is made clear enough to answer.

Comment: What I meant by "index points" was if these two pieces of data corresponded to the `@columnumber` as there array entry positions. i.e in positions `0` and `1` respectively. The question really does need to be clearer as to the varied data that is being collected. Right now I just see columns `0` and `1` being paired together, so it doesn't give a full picture of the overall output. Adding some relevant document detail ( forget the fields you won't touch ) and expected output makes the goal clearer.

Comment: I edited the question with a third column and added it to the end result, hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: I'll take a quick stab, is all you want to do is create a single document out of all array entries but transforming the `@name` to properties? Aggregation is likely not what you want here. What is the eventual goal? A new or altered document? Still trying to understand the aggregation concept if any. Note already stated this will not transform data as keys.

Comment: I edited further. The end result is hopefully the SQL result this was converted from -- it's visible (to me at least) that it got converted into XML and then into JSON and I am just trying to recreate the original. All I knew was that MongoDB recommended aggregation queries to restructure a document, it might not be the right tool for the job if it can't move values into keys.

Comment: Well the XML conversion seemed pretty obvious as many parsers share this same horrible JSON conversion ( I call it a conspiricy ). I still don't see any aggregation happening here, so I believe you are probably better off iterating a cursor and possibly outputing to a new collection. MapReduce can "sort of" handle the job "server side", but it does have it's own strict output format `{ "_id": id, "values": { // the rest } }` which might not be ideal for another collection ouput. The custom nature of tranformations is also more "language like". Hit the chat if you think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

is viewentry also a list?

if you do an aggregate on the collection, and $unwind on viewentry.entrydata you will get one document for every entrydata.  It should be possible to the do a $project to reformat these documents to produce the output you need

Answer (score 0):

this is a nice challenge,

to get outupt like that:

```
{
    "_id" : "161E",
    "field" : [
        {
            "name" : "$Created",
            "datetime" : {
            "0" : "20081027T114133,55+01"
            }
        },
        {
        "name" : "WriteLog",
        "textlist" : {
        "text" : [
            {
                "0" : "2008.OCT.28 12:54:39 CET# EMI"
            },
            {
                "0" : "2008.OCT.28 12:56:13 CET# EMI"
            }   
        ]   }   }   ]}
```

use this aggregation pipelines:

```
db.chx.aggregate([ {$unwind: "$viewentry"}
,  {$unwind: "$viewentry.entrydata"}
,{$group:{
            "_id":"$viewentry.@noteid", field:{ $push:{ 
            "name": "$viewentry.entrydata.@name" , 
            datetime:"$viewentry.entrydata.datetime", 
            textlist:"$viewentry.entrydata.textlist" }}
            }}

    ]).pretty()
```

the next step should be extracting log entries, but I have no idea, as my brain is already fried tonight - so probably I can return later...

Comment: Yeah, well, that doesn't move the name into the propertyname... but it's a start.

Comment: so there are a few questions: 1. can this be done in more than one go? 2. will this be executed frequently?, 3. is this a part of bigger ETL process?. so come to this chat and we can try to solve tis problem http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104903/mongo-queries-issues